# Issue while playing video in full screen mode using MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayer

I have a problem while playing a video in full screen mode using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` (works perfectly in normal mode).

**CODE:**

```
if (PlayV) {
    self.previewView.hidden=NO;
    self.videoController =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:self.videoURL];

    [self.videoController.view setFrame:self.previewView .frame];
    self.videoController.view.center=self.playBtn.center;
    [self.previewView addSubview:self.videoController.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.videoController];
    self.videoController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    self.videoController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    [self.videoController play];
}
```

Comment: Please improve the format of your code

Comment: @objectiveCoder Post your solution an *answer*, not a comment. Stackoverflow is not a forum and is unlike any other site you've likely used, so read the [faq].

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. Add this line of code in `playBtnAction` method:

```
- (IBAction)playBtnAction:(id)sender {
    [self.videoController setFullscreen:YES animated:YES]; 
}
```

and then add this line of code in your `videoPlayBackDidFinish`.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player=[notification object];
if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) { 
    [player.view removeFromSuperview]; 
}
```

This code will check if the video is in fullscreen mode and bring it back to normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagepath]]; //moviePlayer declared in .h and set URL

moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(364, 89, 660, 668); //set custom frame
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view]; //add to view
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
```

This may help you.